# where is the 'index out of range' in my code?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to add all the numbers in an array before the number 13 shows up, if not then sum up all the numbers into a function.

```
def sum13(nums):
  a = 0
  if len(nums) == 0:
    return 0
  elif len(nums) == 1:
    if nums[0] == 13:
      return 0
    return nums
  elif len(nums) >= 2:
    for i in range(len(nums)-1):
      if nums[a] == 13:
        a = a
      else:
        a += nums[i]
    return a
```

Error:
`index out of range`

Comment: format your code properly.

Comment: depending in your input list `a += nums[i]` might get too large such that `nums[a]` will be out of range.

Answer (score 0):

This can be written so much shorter and cleaner:

```
def sum13(nums):
    s = 0
    for x in nums:
        if x == 13:
            break
        s += x
    return s

my_list = [1, 5, 5, 4, 13, 7, 2]
print(sum13(my_list)) # 15
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to index into `nums` with `a` just use `in` and break when *you see* a `13`:

```
def sum13(nums):
  total = 0
  for num in nums:
    if num == 13:
      break #  or return total
    total += num
  return total
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that does not use break statements, accounts for 13 not being in the array, and ends when the number 13 is reached.

```
def sums13(nums):
    result = 0
    if(len(nums) ==0):
        return result
    else:
        for i in range(0,len(nums)):
            if(nums[i] == 13):
                return result
            else:
                result += nums[i]
    return result #This is the case where 13 is not in the array, but we have reached the end of the array.
```

Alternatively, we can simplify this farther by removing the If/Else to start the function, since if the list of numbers is empty, the for loop will not run.

```
def sums13(nums):
    result = 0
    for i in range(0,len(nums)):
        if(nums[i] == 13):
            return result
        else:
            result += nums[i]
    return result #This is the case where 13 is not in the array, but we have reached the end of the array. Also includes the array being empty.
```

Break statements are generally indicated as bad practice and should try to be avoided. Here is a list of test statements based on your requirements

```
>>> nums=[1,5,7,13,14,15]
>>> sums13(nums)
13
>>> nums=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
>>> sums13(nums)
28
>>> nums = []
>>> sums13(nums)
0
>>> nums=[13]
>>> sums13(nums)
0
```

We can also eliminate range part of the for loop and remove the indexing portion for even further simplification!

```
def sums13(nums):
    result = 0
    for number in nums:
        if(number == 13):
            return result
        else:
            result += number
    return result #This is the case where 13 is not in the array, but we have reached the end
```

Maybe I could get fancy with an inline-if statement, but maybe not...